# Very tall image not showing up in images.xcassets and scrollview (IOS8 swift)

Tags: image, swift, ios8, scrollview

I have a very tall image (400px x 50000px, 1.6Mo) that I would like to display inside a scrollView.

When I import it to the images.xcassets, the img preview is blank. The image also doesn't show up in the scrollview (although the scroll bar seems to be ok in term of height).

Any idea what could be the problem? (using a smaller image works fine hence no issue with the code) 
Are there any IOS limitations?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: did you try aspect fit view mode?

Comment: yep I tried but still .. what's weird is that Im not event able to see the picture in the images.xcassets ..